# How to display code snippets in Sharepoint web pages

Tags: html, sharepoint

I am creating an internal web page using Sharepoint, which could be viewed by my team members only. I would like to include some python or JS code within the text of the web page. Does anyone know how to include code snippets so that the code stands out from the rest of the text (as it does on stackoverflow)?

Older versions of Sharepoint allowed Editing HTML source, but it does not look like that option exists anymore.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

We can use Script Editor web part to achieve this.

First Add a script editor web part into your page as below:
[image]

Then click "EDIT SNIPPET" of this web part to add our HTML/JavaScript/PHP code within "xmp" tag.

For example as below:

[image]

Finally, save your changes and you will see what you want!

[image]